# how to query redis Db using golang if its up and running for taking connections?

Tags: go, redis

My redis db has huge number of keys, so when I start my code, at that time if I do info persistence (on redis CLI) it gives me following, Loading: 1 means that redis is not ready to take the connections,while loading :0 means redis up and running and ready to take connections.

```
loading:1
rdb_changes_since_last_save:1024
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1530558451
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1 
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
```

My code to establish the connection with redis is as follows:

```
var DefaultPool = NewPool("redis", 6379)

/*NewPool - create a new redis pool accessible at the given address */
func NewPool(host string, port int) *redis.Pool {
  var address string
  if os.Getenv("DOCKER") != "" {
    address = fmt.Sprintf("%v:6379", host)
  } else {
    address = fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%v", port)
  }
   return &redis.Pool{
     MaxIdle:   80,
     MaxActive: 1000, // max number of connections
     Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
        c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        return c, err
      },
   }
}
```

How I can constantly check if loading value is 0.

Comment: Can you post the code with your attempted implementation and details on the issue you ran into?

Comment: I have posted the code for making connection with redis, but what i dont know is how to query if the loading value is 0 which we get by "info persistence" on redis cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the info:

```
 info, err := redis.String(c.Do("INFO", "persistence"))
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
```

Check the loading field:

```
 re := regexp.MustCompile("^loading:0$") // this can be done once and stored as a package level variable.
 if re.MatchString(info) {
       // loading is zero!
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, how we can check this thing every 10 miliseconds ?

Comment: @NidhiSharma Call the code above in a loop.  Either loop and [sleep](https://godoc.org/time#Sleep) on each iteration or range over a [ticker channel](https://godoc.org/time#Ticker.C).